# How can I calculate the length of the legs of a right triangle with only the hypotenuse and aspect ratio?

Tags: c++

The point of the program is to tell you the width and height of your monitor given that you know the diagonal size and the aspect ratio.  Here is the code I have so far but I am not sure how to correctly calculate the widthIn and heightIn when given the data.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double width, height, diagonal, widthIn, heightIn, aspectRatio, mathPlaceholder;

//Data Collection
cout << "Enter the width value of the display: ";
cin >> width;

cout << "Enter the height value of the display: ";
cin >> height;

cout << "Enter the length of the diagonal in inches: ";
cin >> diagonal;

//Calculations


//Outputting Results
cout << "\n The width of your display is " << widthIn << " inches." << endl;
cout << "The height of your display is " << heightIn << " inches." << endl;



return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question; it's a math question. Review your trigonometry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because thsi is a math question.

Comment: Your code asks the width and height, not the aspect ratio, so just print out the width and height...

Comment: omg close this omg programming omg off topic close this omg

Answer (score 4):

You can use Pythagoras to calculate the sides.

```
height^2+width^2 = diagonal^2 (1)
```

Since you know the aspect ratio, which is given by

```
ratio = width:height (2)
```

you can substitute (2) into (1) and get

```
height^2 + (ratio*height)^2 = diagonal^2  
(1+ratio^2)*height^2 = diagonal^2  
height = sqrt(diagonal^2/(1+ratio^2))
```

using (2) again

```
width  = ratio * height
```